# Can db-aware and non-aware components be used simultaneously to insert/update databases?

Tags: database, delphi

I have a typical [Delphi] set-up for connecting to an external database--a Connection component hooked onto a Table, a DataSetProvider, ClientDataSet, and DataSource. I can successfully insert a new record with code like this:

```
CDS.Insert;
CDS['advisor_id']:=1;
CDS['some_field']:=edtSomeField.Text;
//etc.
CDS.Post;
```

However, I also have a DBLookupComboBox whose DataSource connects to CDS, with ListSource, etc. set to list advisor names and translate them to values for the advisor_id field. It displays what it's supposed to display. I did not err in how I set it up.

If I comment out `CDS['advisor_id']:=1;` and enable the DBLookupComboBox, assuming it will provide the field's value, I receive an error message right after the CDS.Insert line. The message tells me "Field advisor_id must have a value." (Note that if I excange the two assignment lines above, the error message will tell me "Field some_field must have a value.")

Is it possible to mix db-aware and non-db-aware components this way? (Or should I just load a ComboBox with advisor names and transform them to advisor_id values when a user inserts or updates a record?)

Comment: This sounds weird as a constraint check on NULL values should be performed while posting and not after the insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this was down voted but .... It looks like the answer to my question is "no." I think, maybe, clicking the DBLookupComboBox changes the dataset's state. Ultimately, this state change combined with my call to Insert yields the error. Feel free to add a clarifying comment if my understanding is muddled.

For now I think my issue is solved by using the DBLookupComboBox with a connection to a ListSource (so values are displayed and selected), but without a connection to a DataSource (so there's no db state changes). I now have this code:

```
//note that I am omitting error checking and validation code here ...
CDS.Insert;
CDS['advisor_id']:=DBLookupComboBox.KeyValue;
CDS['someField']:=edtSomeField.Text;
//etc.
CDS.Post;
```

Comment: Changing the DBLookupComboBox will most likely change the state to dsEdit if you have only called Open on the CDS.  If you want to Insert, place the CDS in that state before the user changes the DBLookupComboBox value.  Calling Insert when the CDS is in Edit mode will force a Post to occur before placing the CDS into Insert which is probably where the error is coming from but does seem strange if you have hooked up the DataSource property correctly.  You could assign 'someField' in the BeforePost event perhaps.  You technically can do what you want.